# Remove multiple elements in tMap-output

Tags: talend, tmap

I make a lookup in my tMap to fill a list of articles in my model. In my output I want the model-element with all article elements like this:

```
<RfidModel>
    <Model>
        <Modellnummer>696968</Modellnummer>
        <ArtikelListe>
            <Artikel>
                <Artikelnummer/>
                <FarbNr>10</FarbNr>
            </Artikel>
            <Artikel>
                <Artikelnummer/>
                <FarbNr>70</FarbNr>
            </Artikel>
            <Artikel>
                <Artikelnummer/>
                <FarbNr>93</FarbNr>
            </Artikel>
        </ArtikelListe>
    </Model>
</RfidModel>
```

But what I get ist this:

```
<RfidModel>
    <Model>
        <Modellnummer>696968</Modellnummer>
        <ArtikelListe>
            <Artikel>
                <Artikelnummer/>
                <FarbNr>10</FarbNr>
            </Artikel>
        </ArtikelListe>
    </Model>
</RfidModel> 

<RfidModel>
    <Model>
        <Modellnummer>696968</Modellnummer>
        <ArtikelListe>
            <Artikel>
                <Artikelnummer/>
                <FarbNr>10</FarbNr>
            </Artikel>
            <Artikel>
                <Artikelnummer/>
                <FarbNr>70</FarbNr>
            </Artikel>
        </ArtikelListe>
    </Model>
</RfidModel> 

<RfidModel>
    <Model>
        <Modellnummer>696968</Modellnummer>
        <ArtikelListe>
            <Artikel>
                <Artikelnummer/>
                <FarbNr>10</FarbNr>
            </Artikel>
            <Artikel>
                <Artikelnummer/>
                <FarbNr>70</FarbNr>
            </Artikel>
            <Artikel>
                <Artikelnummer/>
                <FarbNr>93</FarbNr>
            </Artikel>
        </ArtikelListe>
    </Model>
</RfidModel>
```

In my tMap I configured the element Artikel as a loop-element. How can I solve my problem?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add information how you data structure looks like, how your tMap is configured and how you create your output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to use tXMLMap and no tMap. 
Then after selecting Artikel as loop element, select the option "all in one" in the "tXMLMap settings" of the tXMLMap output.